# How to get mobile compatible icon in Google Search Results?

Tags: search-engine

I notice that in google mobile search result a small green mobile icon is showed for some sites indicating mobile version.But all sites does not seem to get so in the search results.For example mashable.com has mobile version of its site but green icon is not shown but say for labnol.org a green mobile icon is shown,Similar many blog have mobile version but they dont seem to get that mobile icon in search result.My site is powered by wordpress how to get such icon in result.And my site is made ready for mobile users.

But how to get such mobile icon in google search result that's what i want to know...

Examples

http://img857.imageshack.us/i/googleresultmobileicon1.jpg/

http://img836.imageshack.us/i/googleresultmobileicon2.jpg/

Answer (score 1):

Just add this in your header

```
<link rel="alternate" media="handheld" url="YOUR URL" />
```

That's it! Don't forget to fetch the Google mobile bot in your webmastertools and wait for a day or two. :)

Comment: I didn't get you. What to add in header ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a forum post from [mobility.mobi](http://mobility.mobi/showthread.php?11934-Mobile-phone-icon-on-google-mobile-search).

> ok i finally got my icon. And i didnt create a site map. All i did so far is i added this in the head. `<link rel="alternate" media="handheld" href="http://www.myurl.mobi" />` and waited for a month :-)

I would assume you would want to actually have a mobile-friendly website to put there.

Also, I bet jehzlau did put the code in his post, but didn't use `` when he did it (I just noticed that my code wasn't there when I quoted).